# How to delete Empty Range for entire workbook excluding a few sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

In my workbook, I want to go through each sheet, excluding 3 specific sheets, and check the range `A8:A12`. Within that range, if the cell is empty, I would like to delete the entire row. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub deleteRows()

   Dim QSh As Worksheet
   
   Dim rngDel As Range
   
   Set rngDel = Range("A8:A12")

   For Each QSh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        If QSh.Name <> "Sheet1" And QSh.Name <> "Sheet2" And QSh.Name <> "Sheet3" Then
    
        QSh.rngDel.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        
    End If

End Sub
```

Doesn't seem to work, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Here are three things I see

- `rngDel` is set before looping each worksheet, meaning it is implicitly bound only to the `ActiveSheet`. What you have  is the same thing as `Set rngDel = Activesheet.Range("A8:A12")`
- `QSh.rngDel` is incorrect, as `rngDel` is a variable and not a property of `QSh`.
- There is no `Next` for your For Loop.

One additional thing from @bigben is that there needs to be some type of error handling for when/if there are no blank cells.

With that, this should work using your code:

```vb
Sub deleteRows()
   Dim QSh As Worksheet
    For Each QSh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If QSh.Name <> "Sheet1" And QSh.Name <> "Sheet2" And QSh.Name <> "Sheet3" Then
            On Error Resume Next
                QSh.Range("A8:A12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next ' <~ Missing
End Sub
```

Comment: Great point, @BigBen. Added a simple error handling for the demo. Cheers

Comment: Yep. Another option is to use `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank`... either gets the job done.